# How to write Unicode string in Jtextfield in java using Locale property.

Tags: java, swing, unicode, localization

Hy,
I want to write dynamically (on run time) some text(other then english, could be arabic,chinese e.t.c) in JTextField.

**Using Hardcoded Logic.** I am able to write this using hardcoded logic by explicitly managing each key . It is like this.

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
      char ch=evt.getKeyChar();            
        evt.consume();
   String text = ""; 
   switch(ch){
            case 'a':
                text=text+"\u0627";
                break;
            case 'A':
                text=text+"\u0622";
                break;
     }
   jTextField1.setText(text);

}
```

**Using Locale Class.**
I am wondering, how to do this dynamically. For this i have explored Locale Class of java. I am able to get a list of all countries and supported languages , codes e.t.c. 
I am using this code to set the locale of a textfield dynamically to Japanese, but **still it writes in english**.

```
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ja").build();
jTextField1.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(aLocale);
```

Also what I have understood is that java localization for swing components is independent of underlying host operating system localization. So if that's the case , then why doesn't the java text field let me input some other character(other then english), when I press some any key from keyboard?

Or is there any method of doing it?

I am doing some research project and I am stuck here. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: check if the `selectInputMethod` return true.

Comment: I have selected the arabic language, it returns false. But i downloaded the language pack of arabic in windows, and then when i run it , it returns true.

Comment: I suggest you to read this javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html#selectInputMethod(java.util.Locale)

Comment: Thanks. I get that. But it means that we can only type in text field, if our windows or host operating system has that language installed. If i am correct.

Comment: actually i think that you also need to configure your keyboard to that language

Comment: Well. thanks. i guess that's the only option left.